# XML: generate tags with prefix from namespaces

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I need to generate an XML using different prefix that represent namespaces:

For example, I've this list of namespaces:

```
class XMLNamespaces:
   empty="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
   cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
   cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
   ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" 
   ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
   ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" 
   qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" 
   sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1" 
   udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" 
   xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
# create XML 

NSMAP={None:XMLNamespaces.empty, 'cac':XMLNamespaces.cac, 'cbc':XMLNamespaces.cbc,
        'ccts':XMLNamespaces.ccts, 'ds':XMLNamespaces.ds, 'ext':XMLNamespaces.ext,
        'qdt':XMLNamespaces.qdt, 'sac':XMLNamespaces.sac, 'udt':XMLNamespaces.udt,
        'xsi':XMLNamespaces.xsi}
```

And I'd like to generate this structure:

**Only the Invoice tag has the full namespaces.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" 
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" 
xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" 
xmlns:sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1" 
xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
     <ext:UBLExtension>
         <ext:ExtensionContent>
            <sac:AdditionalInformation>
            </sac:AdditionalInformation>
         </ext:ExtensionContent>
     </ext:UBLExtension>
</Invoice>
```

**My code:**

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import Element, SubElement, QName, tostring

class XMLNamespaces:
   empty="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
   cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
   cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
   ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" 
   ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
   ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" 
   qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" 
   sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1" 
   udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" 
   xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"


NSMAP={None:XMLNamespaces.empty, 'cac':XMLNamespaces.cac, 'cbc':XMLNamespaces.cbc,
        'ccts':XMLNamespaces.ccts, 'ds':XMLNamespaces.ds, 'ext':XMLNamespaces.ext,
        'qdt':XMLNamespaces.qdt, 'sac':XMLNamespaces.sac, 'udt':XMLNamespaces.udt,
        'xsi':XMLNamespaces.xsi}


invoice = etree.Element("Invoice", nsmap=NSMAP) # lxml only!
ublextensions = etree.SubElement(invoice, "UBLExtensions", nsmap=NSMAP['ext'])

print(etree.tostring(invoice, pretty_print=True))
```

But it returns:

```
File "xml-building.py", line 27, in <module>
    ublextensions = etree.SubElement(invoice, "UBLExtensions", nsmap=NSMAP['ext'])
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3135, in lxml.etree.SubElement
  File "src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi", line 199, in lxml.etree._makeSubElement
  File "src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi", line 193, in lxml.etree._makeSubElement
  File "src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi", line 213, in lxml.etree._setNodeNamespaces
  File "src\lxml\apihelpers.pxi", line 274, in lxml.etree._iter_nsmap
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType
```

Comment: The `nsmap` value must be a dictionary. `NSMAP['ext']` is  string, and that is why you get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add the `nsmap` in the subelements.  Remove that and add in curly brackets, before the id of each element, the desired namespace (see below, I use an additional dictionary for that).  It will work as you want:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import Element, SubElement, QName, tostring

class XMLNamespaces:
   empty="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
   cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
   cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
   ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
   ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
   ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
   qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"
   sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1"
   udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"
   xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

NSMAP={None:XMLNamespaces.empty, 'cac':XMLNamespaces.cac, 'cbc':XMLNamespaces.cbc,
        'ccts':XMLNamespaces.ccts, 'ds':XMLNamespaces.ds, 'ext':XMLNamespaces.ext,
        'qdt':XMLNamespaces.qdt, 'sac':XMLNamespaces.sac, 'udt':XMLNamespaces.udt,
        'xsi':XMLNamespaces.xsi}

ns = {k:'{' + v + '}' for k,v in NSMAP.items()}

invoice = etree.Element("Invoice", nsmap=NSMAP) # lxml only!
ublextensions = etree.SubElement(invoice, f"{ns['ext']}UBLExtensions")
ublextension = etree.SubElement(ublextensions, f"{ns['ext']}UBLExtension")
extcontent = etree.SubElement(ublextension, f"{ns['ext']}ExtensionContent")
addinfo = etree.SubElement(extcontent, f"{ns['sac']}AdditionalInformation")

print(etree.tostring(invoice, pretty_print=True).decode('ascii'))
```

Result:

```
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
 xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
 xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
 xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2"
 xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
 xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
 xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2"
 xmlns:sac="urn:sunat:names:specification:ubl:peru:schema:xsd:SunatAggregateComponents-1"
 xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
      <ext:ExtensionContent>
        <sac:AdditionalInformation/>
      </ext:ExtensionContent>
    </ext:UBLExtension>
  </ext:UBLExtensions>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: This works, but I would use `QName` to create the subelements. That would eliminate the need for all the curly brackets.

Comment: Sure!  I just was following the initial example.

Comment: @JCGonzalez So the inner most tag will only contain a "closing" tag if no text provided.  apart from that, would you provide the example using QName. Thank you.

Comment: @OmarGonzales Simply substitute the *f-strings* (`f"..."`), that include the tag name with the qualification prefix, with the **Q**ualified **Name** class `QName(namespace, tag)`.  The first one would result: `ublextensions = etree.SubElement(invoice, QName(NSMAP['ext'], 'UBLExtensions'))` (you don't need the `ns` dictionary anymore).